# Is there code for jquery when redirected from x run script

Tags: jquery, html, redirect

I made a splash page that redirects to a home page when clicked. The homepage has 3 galleries. Now my boss wants direct links from splash page to each of the galleries, but the galleries are loaded by replacing a div on button click.

I poked around to see if there was a way I could have my `<a>` be created in a way to run a script when the next page is loaded, but it seems impossible. So what if I make the direct links open blank re-direct pages. I have seen some if redirected from x run this script to squelch hotlinking.

Would it be possible to setup x.html and have it onload redirect to mainpage.html, then have mainpage listen for redirects from the specific pages to run specific scripts?

Sorry for kind of rambling.

Comment: Why don't you just send an attribute in your link and check for that? Sorry I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but seems like a really easy problem. EDIT: When you read the attribute just trigger a click on the button that loads the gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your splash.html page, you should include links pointing to the mainpage.html with extra parameters to specify which gallery to trigger. 
Either:

```
mainpage.html?gallerie=3
```

or

```
mainpage.html#gallerie_3
```

Then in your mainpage.html, you place a JS code that executes when the page loads that will check if the gallerie parameter is specified, and if so, you run your script.

Comment: I didn't realize I could put special tags at the end of an html without needing separate pages. Thanks.